# I got a power loss and my directory became a file (ext4, ssd), what to do?

Tags: filesystems, ext4

After a power loss 1 directory (maybe more, I don't know) just became a file on my SSD (ext4 fs):

```
-rw-------  1 postgres      postgres       16K May 15 20:06 stolon
```

It was a directory! How could it happen?
And can I make it <s>great</s> directory again?

Comment: Have you run a file system check?

Comment: No, I didn't. I had 2 replicas of all files. After restarting Stolon without this "file" it just recreated everything. But didn't know this can happen on ext4. I thought it is kinda protected from power loss.